# How to use joblib.Memory of cache the output of a member function of a Python Class

Tags: python, caching, memory, decorator, joblib

I would like to cache the output of a member function of a class using `joblib.Memory` library. Here is a sample code:

```
import joblib
import numpy as np

mem = joblib.Memory(cachedir='/tmp', verbose=1)


@mem.cache
def my_sum(x):
    return np.sum(x)


class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @mem.cache
    def my_sum(self, x):
        return np.sum(x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
    a = TestClass()
    print a.my_sum(x)  # does not work
    print my_sum(x) # works fine
```

However, I get the following error:

```
/nfs/sw/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/joblib/memory.pyc in _get_output_dir(self, *args, **kwargs)
    512             of the function called with the given arguments.
    513         """
--> 514         argument_hash = self._get_argument_hash(*args, **kwargs)
    515         output_dir = os.path.join(self._get_func_dir(self.func),
    516                                   argument_hash)

/nfs/sw/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/joblib/memory.pyc in _get_argument_hash(self, *args, **kwargs)
    505     def _get_argument_hash(self, *args, **kwargs):
    506         return hashing.hash(filter_args(self.func, self.ignore,
--> 507                                          args, kwargs),
    508                              coerce_mmap=(self.mmap_mode is not None))
    509 

/nfs/sw/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/joblib/func_inspect.pyc in filter_args(func, ignore_lst, args, kwargs)
    228                            repr(args)[1:-1],
    229                            ', '.join('%s=%s' % (k, v)
--> 230                                     for k, v in kwargs.items())
    231                            )
    232                         )

ValueError: Wrong number of arguments for my_sum(self, x):
     my_sum(array([1, 2, 3, 4]), ) was called.
```

Is there a way to cache a member function of a class using Memory or any other decorators?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The following excerpt is taken from https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/memory.html#gotchas

> caching methods: you cannot decorate a method at class definition,
> because when the class is instantiated, the first argument (self) is
> bound, and no longer accessible to the Memory object. The following
> code won’t work:
>
> ```
> class Foo(object):
>
>     @mem.cache  # WRONG
>     def method(self, args):
>         pass
> ```
>
> The right way to do this is to decorate at instantiation time:
>
> ```
> class Foo(object):
>
>     def __init__(self, args):
>         self.method = mem.cache(self.method)
>
>     def method(self, ...):
>         pass
> ```

Comment: One should read the caveat in that documentation, if _any_ attribute of `self` is modified then the cache is invalidated and method called afresh, adding `ignore=['self']` is advised and seems to fix that for me ...

Comment: Make so to only ignore `self` if none of the `self` attributes affects the return value of the cached method.