# SageMaker sklearn model upload and endpoint creation failure

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, scikit-learn, amazon-sagemaker, host

I trained a sklearn model and stored it as a `.joblib` file. This is a large model, about 13.5 gb big. You can download it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14t9ZhToiH2LlXrV7FCZX0StKKUX1bnbG/view?usp=sharing)

I want to upload this model to sagemaker and crete an endpoint to access it. To do so, I have been following this [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/deploying-a-pre-trained-sklearn-model-on-amazon-sagemaker-826a2b5ac0b6), with a few changes

My `inference.py` file is as follows:

```
import joblib
import os
import json

"""
Deserialize fitted model
"""
def model_fn(model_dir):
    model = joblib.load(os.path.join(model_dir, "model.joblib"))
    return model

"""
input_fn
    request_body: The body of the request sent to the model.
    request_content_type: (string) specifies the format/variable type of the request
"""
def input_fn(request_body, request_content_type):
    if request_content_type == 'application/json':
        request_body = json.loads(request_body)
        inpVar = request_body['Input']
        return inpVar
    else:
        raise ValueError("This model only supports str input")
"""
predict_fn
    input_data: returned array from input_fn above
    model (sklearn model) returned model loaded from model_fn above
"""
def predict_fn(input_data, model):
    return model.predict(input_data)

"""
output_fn
    prediction: the returned value from predict_fn above
    content_type: the content type the endpoint expects to be returned. Ex: JSON, string
"""

def output_fn(prediction, content_type):
    res = int(prediction[0])
    respJSON = {'Output': res}
    return respJSON
```

My `main.py` file is as follows. I had to change `instance_type` in `image_uri` and `endpoint_config_response`to `ml.m5.2xlarge` to accomodate the size of the model, and updated `image_uri` version to `version="1.2-1"`

```
import boto3
import json
import os
import joblib
import pickle
import tarfile
import sagemaker
from sagemaker.estimator import Estimator
import time
from time import gmtime, strftime
import subprocess


#Setup
client = boto3.client(service_name="sagemaker")
runtime = boto3.client(service_name="sagemaker-runtime")
boto_session = boto3.session.Session()
s3 = boto_session.resource('s3')
region = boto_session.region_name
print(region)
sagemaker_session = sagemaker.Session()
role = 'arn role'

#Build tar file with model data + inference code
bashCommand = "tar -cvpzf model.tar.gz model.joblib inference.py"
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = process.communicate()

# retrieve sklearn image
image_uri = sagemaker.image_uris.retrieve(
    framework="sklearn",
    region=region,
    version="1.2-1",
    py_version="py3",
    instance_type='ml.m5.2xlarge',
)

#Bucket for model artifacts
default_bucket = 'bucketname'
print(default_bucket)

#Upload tar.gz to bucket
model_artifacts = f"s3://{default_bucket}/model.tar.gz"
response = s3.meta.client.upload_file('model.tar.gz', default_bucket, 'model.tar.gz')

#Step 1: Model Creation
model_name = "sklearn-test" + strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", gmtime())
print("Model name: " + model_name)
create_model_response = client.create_model(
    ModelName=model_name,
    Containers=[
        {
            "Image": image_uri,
            "Mode": "SingleModel",
            "ModelDataUrl": model_artifacts,
            "Environment": {'SAGEMAKER_SUBMIT_DIRECTORY': model_artifacts,
                           'SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM': 'inference.py'} 
        }
    ],
    ExecutionRoleArn=role,
)
print("Model Arn: " + create_model_response["ModelArn"])


#Step 2: EPC Creation
sklearn_epc_name = "sklearn-epc" + strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", gmtime())
endpoint_config_response = client.create_endpoint_config(
    EndpointConfigName=sklearn_epc_name,
    ProductionVariants=[
        {
            "VariantName": "sklearnvariant",
            "ModelName": model_name,
            "InstanceType": 'ml.m5.2xlarge',
            "InitialInstanceCount": 1
        },
    ],
)
print("Endpoint Configuration Arn: " + endpoint_config_response["EndpointConfigArn"])


#Step 3: EP Creation
endpoint_name = "sklearn-local-ep" + strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", gmtime())
print('endpoint name', endpoint_name)
create_endpoint_response = client.create_endpoint(
    EndpointName=endpoint_name,
    EndpointConfigName=sklearn_epc_name,
)
print("Endpoint Arn: " + create_endpoint_response["EndpointArn"])


#Monitor creation
describe_endpoint_response = client.describe_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name)
while describe_endpoint_response["EndpointStatus"] == "Creating":
    describe_endpoint_response = client.describe_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name)
    print(describe_endpoint_response["EndpointStatus"])
    time.sleep(15)
print(describe_endpoint_response)
```

When i run the code, i get to the last step, where it tries to create the model for 30 min and then fails. Looking at the cloudwatch logs, i see two errors:

```
69.254.178.2 - - [05/May/2023:18:32:33 +0000] "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "-" "AHC/2.0"

2023/05/05 18:32:38 [crit] 28#28: *202 connect() to unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 169.254.178.2, server: , request: "GET /ping HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock:/ping", host: "169.254.180.2:8080"

[2023-05-05 18:46:46 +0000] [216] [ERROR] Error handling request /ping

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/_functions.py", line 93, in wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/ml/code/inference.py", line 9, in model_fn
    model = joblib.load(os.path.join(model_dir, "model.joblib"))
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 658, in load
    obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 577, in _unpickle
    obj = unpickler.load()
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/pickle.py", line 1212, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/pickle.py", line 1537, in load_stack_global
    self.append(self.find_class(module, name))
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/pickle.py", line 1579, in find_class
    __import__(module, level=0)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.sparse._csr'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 55, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener_name, req, client, addr)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 143, in handle_request
    super().handle_request(listener_name, req, sock, addr)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 106, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sagemaker_sklearn_container/serving.py", line 140, in main
    user_module_transformer, execution_parameters_fn = import_module(serving_env.module_name,
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sagemaker_sklearn_container/serving.py", line 126, in import_module
    user_module_transformer.initialize()
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/_transformer.py", line 185, in initialize
    self._model = self._model_fn(_env.model_dir)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/_functions.py", line 95, in wrapper
    six.reraise(error_class, error_class(e), sys.exc_info()[2])
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 55, in handle self.handle_request(listener_name, req, client, addr) File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 143, in handle_request super().handle_request(listener_name, req, sock, addr) File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 106, in handle_request respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response) File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sagemaker_sklearn_container/serving.py", line 140, in main user_module_transformer, execution_parameters_fn = import_module(serving_env.module_name, File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sagemaker_sklearn_container/serving.py", line 126, in import_module user_module_transformer.initialize() File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/_transformer.py", line 185, in initialize self._model = self._model_fn(_env.model_dir) File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/_functions.py", line 95, in wrapper six.reraise(error_class, error_class(e), sys.exc_info()[2])
```

Why are these errors happening?

These errors are in cloudwatch, not my terminal. So please tell me how to install these libraries in sagemaker.

And how do i fix it?

I trained the model and used this deployments script in python 3.9.16

Comment: I think you might need to install joblib in sagemaker.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: Looks like you need to install scipy

Comment: where do i install it? and how?

Answer (score 0):

I will advice you also to cache the model in memory, more over if it's a big model, so that it doesn't have to be loaded from disk all the time.
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39020217/how-to-use-joblib-memory-of-cache-the-output-of-a-member-function-of-a-python-cl) for that.

Summary:

```py
import joblib

mem = joblib.Memory(cachedir='/tmp', verbose=1)

def _get_model(model_dir):
    modl = joblib.load(os.path.join(model_dir, "model.joblib"))
    return modl

def model_fn(model_dir):
    """
    Deserialize fitted model
    """
    get_model = mem.cache(_get_model)
    return get_model(model_dir)
```

Or another method:

```py
def cache2mem(func):
    cache = {}

    def wrapper(*args):
        if args in cache:
            return cache[args]
        else:
            result = func(*args)
            cache[args] = result
            return result

    return wrapper

@cache2mem
def model_fn(model_dir):
    """
    Deserialize fitted model
    """
    return joblib.load(os.path.join(model_dir, "model.joblib"))
```